# Separation of function declaration and definition in Swift

Tags: swift, encapsulation

I'm having a look at the new Swift. I come from C, C++, Objective-C... I notice that in swift is not possible (?) to separate the declaration and the definition of functions. The result of this is that structure and class declarations are very long and bloated, and it is therefore difficult to have a "quick picture" of the class by looking at the code. Am I doing something wrong? Is there any approach to overcome this problem, besides trying to make functions small, etc.? Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you are not doing something wrong Swift is. They tossed the "Write to the Interface" concept.

Comment: Well, I guess the concept is that for the programmer everything is visible, so there is no real need, theoretically, to have a separate interface. In practice, the problem I see is that it feels harder to keep track of the structure of things... Time will say (?) but right now, yes, this aspect of the language feels a little bit of a mess.

Comment: The other problem is that methods that I have not exposed in the Interface are implementations details that I can change, add and delete at will without any concern that there are other usages that may break the program. Takes the "I" out of the SOLID principles. Now the SOLD principles, quick tell Michael Feathers. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In swift, there is no separation of declaration vs implementation. This works like most other modern languages like Python. If you want to get a quick picture of your class, you should use code folding. Simply fold all your methods and functions. And unfold a method of you want to modify / work on it.

Comment: Uhm... Yeah. Well, maybe with time I'll get used to it. Let's try to be flexible then. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I suspect that some "presentational" aspects of the code are left to the editor (?). You talk about folding (which kind of helps). The issue is similar to the fact of not needing a semicolon at the end of statements. So far, statements are not anymore allowed to break across lines, so for long lines, we'll have to rely on editor's "soft wrap" (?) --true that Swift is not verbose like Objective-C (thankfully!)

Comment: It's not entirely true, because you have "declarations" of the Cocoa API and Swift standard library but not their implementation. You just can't do this with your own Swift code.

Comment: @newact Apple ships the interface of the Framework/Library to you. I believe this doesn't tell you what the sources of that Framework/Library look like.

Answer (score 2):

Just a crazy way to have public API and private implementation:

*crazy* - stands for factory method `create()` which I do not like to see in swift without real need.

In **AClass.swift** file:

```
// Public API
class AClass {

    private init() {

    }

    class func create() -> AClass {
        return AClassPrivateImplementation()
    }

    // Only method declaration
    func sayHello() {}
}

// Private implementation
private class AClassPrivateImplementation: AClass {

    override func sayHello() {
        privateImplementation()
    }

    func privateImplementation() {
        println("Hello")
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let a = AClass.create()
a.sayHello()
```

**Why it works:** `private` modifier makes things visible only within source file.

**Advantages:** you can define more than one implementation hence additional `createOther()` will be needed.

**Disadvantages:** it looks like Java or C#, not a Swift way :)

Comment: Yes, pretty crazy... Doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 2):

About the best we can do is use protocols as Implementation declarations and mark all private methods:

```
protocol TestInterface {
    var propertyPublic1: String { get }
    func funcPublic1() -> Int
}

class Test : TestInterface {
    var propertyPublic1: String = "text."
    func funcPublic1() -> Int {return 754}

    private var propertyPrivate1: Int = 5678
    private func funcPrivate1() -> Int {return 334}
}

var t = Test()
let propPublic1 = t.propertyPublic1
```

The problem is that it is not provided as a standard idiom and the naming is unfortunate, I have just appended "Interface" to the class name.

Comment: Yeah... but then every class would need its protocol, which is kind of messy (and probably incorrect from design perspective). Moreover, at the end the definition of functions would still have to be written together with the declaration, anyway...

Comment: The protocol could be in a seperate file.

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't let you separate declarations from implementations. This cuts both ways -- on the one hand, you can't (manually) write a header file that describes the interface you want to expose for users of your code. On the other, you don't have to manually keep your header files up to date and in sync with your implementations.

Instead, Swift has an [access control](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=5) mechanism. Use the `public`, `internal` (implied), and `private` keywords to mark which types and functions you intend to expose.

Comment: So, we toss the whole "Write to the Interface" concept? Sure I can mark methods private but that misses declaring which methods are the Interface without reading through the code. Finally Objective-C provided the capability of creating small Interfaces with only the methods being exposed.

Comment: "you can't (manually) write a header file that describes the interface you want to expose" Okay, can you do it not-manually then? Anyway, Apple does it (they describe the interface they want to expose to you without giving you the implementation).

Comment: @newacct Actually, if it cannot be done manually, it's not helpful for what I intend. What I would like is to _write_ implementation/definition separately of the interface/declaration; it's a workflow issue. Being able to ship only the interface to the user doesn't mean that I am able to write them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true that swift doesn't have header files but you can make Xcode generate something similar to this.

This will give you an overview of the class as you mention.

On Xcode go to `Navigation > Jump to Generated Interface`.

This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1914/_index.html) should explain a bit more.